# How to add subscription using websocket using Apollo server with SQL Server database?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using Apollo client to build a graphql server which has query, subscription and mutation.

I have successfully added query by referring to this document: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/b-crud-operations-with-graphql-apollo-server-sequelize-auto-b-711da1803017

When I open the http link, it takes me to the Apollo sandbox. I am able to query here. In settings of this server there is a websocket link. When I use this websocket link in my react app, by using urql and GraphQLWsLink, it shows failed to connect to websocket.

I have configured websocket in my server code like this:

```
const {createServer} = require('http');
const {ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer} = require('apollo-server-core');
const {ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault} = require('apollo-server-core');
const {makeExecutableSchema} = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const {WebSocketServer} = require('ws');
const {useServer} = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/ws');

const { ApolloServer,gql } = require('apollo-server');
var http = require("http");

const fs = require('fs');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const typeDefs = gql(fs.readFileSync('./graphql/typeDefs.graphql',{encoding:'utf-8'}));

console.log("Resolvers", resolvers)

const app = new ApolloServer({typeDefs,resolvers });

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
// ...

const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Creating the WebSocket server
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
   server: httpServer,
   path: '/graphql',
 });

 const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

 const server = new ApolloServer({
   schema,
   csrfPrevention: true,
   cache: "bounded",
   plugins: [
     // Proper shutdown for the HTTP server.
     ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),

     // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
     {
       async serverWillStart() {
         return {
           async drainServer() {
             await serverCleanup.dispose();
           },
         };
       },
     },
     ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
   ],
 });

server.listen(5000).then(({ url }) => { 
   console.log("Server ready at " +   url );     
   });
```

The client side(react) code is as follows:

```
const serverURL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/graphql";
const wsClient = new GraphQLWsLink(createClient({
  url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/graphql',
}));

const client = createClient({
      url: senseopsHTTPServerURL,
      exchanges: [
        ...defaultExchanges,
        subscriptionExchange({
          forwardSubscription: (operation) => ({
            subscribe: (sink) => ({
              unsubscribe: wsClient.subscribe(operation, sink),
            }),
          }),
        }),
      ],
    });
```

I am using this client in my context provider to get the data. It shows "Failed to connect to websocket". How do I fix this?